# как добавить условие в js скрипт?

Tags: javascript

для массового добавления в друзья вк, я использую это:

```
javascript:var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName('friends_find_user_add'); 
console.log(buttons); for(key in buttons){buttons[key].click();}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт добавлял только тех людей, с кем n-ое кол-во общих друзей.

скрипт ниже выводит такого формата текст - 1308 общих друзей

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("friends_find_user_label");
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++)
console.log(div[i].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой вариант:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.friends_find_user_add');
let info = document.querySelectorAll(".friends_find_user_label");

for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  let mutual_friends = Number( info[i].textContent.match(/\d*/)[0] );
  if (mutual_friends > 5) buttons[i].click();
}
```

Называется "регулярное выражение", `\d` - digit, цифры. `*` - ноль или много совпадений подряд.

`.match()` возвращает массив совпадений (строки), откуда достается первый `[0]` элемент (число целиком) и превращается непосредственно в число, через `Number()`

---

Но браузер не любит, когда скрипт сразу кликает по сотням кнопок. Поэтому, было бы правильнее кликать циклом, добавив небольшую задержку после каждого клика. Примерно так:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.friends_find_user_add');
let info = document.querySelectorAll(".friends_find_user_label");

let add_friends = [...buttons].filter((_,i) => info[i].textContent.match(/\d*/)[0] > 5);
// Оставляет только те кнопки, на которые надо кликать.
// google → "JS массивы", "spread оператор", "Array filter", "Стрелочные функции"

let i = 0;
(function _loop() {
  add_friends[i].click();

  if (add_friends[++i]) setTimeout(_loop, 250); // в миллисекундах. По 4 клика в секунду
  // Каждый раз, увеличивая `i`, если в массиве еще есть элементы,
  // функция через таймер вызывает саму себя.
})();
```

---

>> https://learn.javascript.ru/

>> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/

P.s. Фигурные скобки в условиях пропущены, потому что они выполняют одну короткую строчку кода. Если строчка кода длинная, или код многострочный, пишут так:

```
if (условие) {
  // код...
  // код...
  // код...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Оба варианта работают, правда во втором кидает ошибку
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'i' has already been declared
Я удалил эту строку
    let i = 0;
и всё заработало!